# 3d flip animation not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, flip

I wanted to create a card with text which will flip and show a backside with some other text, whenever you click on the "card" (div). I checked for any mistakes and stuff but somehow its not working on chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="card effect__EFFECT">
  <div class="card__front">
    <span class="card__text">front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <span class="card__text">back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
          transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.card__front {
  background-color: #ff5078;
}

.card__back {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__click.flipped .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

Javascript:

```js
(function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.effect__click");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener( card );
  }

  function clickListener(card) {
    card.addEventListener( "click", function() {
      var c = this.classList;
      c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") : c.add("flipped");
    });
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hzsbzxw6/ it seems that this should all work, it could be the way you're embedding the script.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
```

Try fixing that, or ultimately not embedding it inline.